# Automatic sorting of environments by parameters (e.g. by date)

Tags: sectioning, environments, sorting

I desire for some sort of easy system for manipulating "sections" or environments based on additional data such as dates. I did a preliminary google search and couldn't come up with anything because I can't put it into words, but I will try my best to form an example. I am not sure if LaTeX even allows for this in general as I can only compare it to bibtex.

I want to be able to have "entries" or "sections" much like the style of a journal which have an argument for a "date" or some other criteria that they may be sorted by. Some pseudocode:

```
\begin{entry}{1928}{3}{28}
  This is an entry.
\end{entry}

\begin{entry}{1777}{4}{30}
  This is another entry, but dated before the last one.
\end{entry}
```

The goal would then to have---when it compiles---the entries would be automatically sorted by date. That is, the second entry (as it appears in the code) would appear before the first.

Is there any library or anything that would help accomplish this task? It's sort of like how bibtex sorts despite the code order. Anything close to this is also appreciated, whether it operates via sectioning or environments. The goal is to sort by some sort of "tag" like a date. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would try to do that by using BiTeX. Use a `@MISC` record, with `date` and `note` for the entry stuff. And use a format that handles note and performs sorting by date.

Answer (score 2):

To reorder some like sections I would make subdocuments as `19280328.tex`, `17770430.tex`, etc., and then insert in a main document with

```
\input{19280328}
\input{17770430}
...
```

Then any good editor can short this quickly in the correct order

In case of small entries to be showed as a description-like environment, one option could be the package `nomencl`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature
\def\nomname{Cronology}
\begin{document}
\nomenclature{1928/03/28}{This is an entry.}
\nomenclature{1777/04/30}{This is another entry, but dated before the last one.}
\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{0000/00/00xx}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Note that once saved this file, said as `test.tex,` to compile it, you should run:

```
pdflatex test.tex
makeindex test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex # really not needed for this simple example
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to store, sort and print your journal entries.

Since you're using a sensible YYYY-MM-DD representation for the dates, I've combined them into a single field called `date` inside the `journal` database. Sorting is achieved using `\DTLsort{date}{journal}`, after which printing is done by cycling through the database using `\DTLforeach`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool,environ}

\dtlexpandnewvalue
\NewEnviron{entry}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{journal}% Add new row to database
  \DTLnewdbentry{journal}{date}{#1}% Add date entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{journal}{entry}{\BODY}% Add entry body
}

\DTLnewdb{journal}

\newcommand{\printentries}{%
  \section*{Journal}
  \DTLsort{date}{journal}%
  \DTLforeach{journal}{%
    \entrydate=date,
    \entrybody=entry%
  }{%
    \subsection*{\entrydate}
    \entrybody
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{entry}{2018-01-02}
This is an entry.
\end{entry}

\begin{entry}{2017-01-05}
This is another entry.
\end{entry}

\printentries

\end{document}
```

Note that if the entries will contain paragraphs, you'll have to use `\DTLpar` instead of empty lines/linesbreaks. As an example,

```
\begin{entry}{1234-56-78}
First paragraph.
\DTLpar
Second paragraph.
\end{entry}
```